# Bernoulli Process Probability that m-th failure occurs before n-th successes.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are given that the probability of success is $p$ for each trial.

The questions asks me to find the probability that $m$-th failure occurs before the n-th success.

The answer I ended up with is seemingly incorrect, I was told that instead I managed to find the probability that $m$ failures occur before the $n$-th success.

[My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKC1x.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:My second attempt.

[image: Second attempt I consider to be correct]

Comment: The difference is if there are exactly $m$ failures before the $n$th success, or if there are $m$ or more failures before the $n$th success.  So, for example, there might be exactly $m+8$ failures before the $n$th success.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in the question I posted. I meant to say m-th failure before the n-th success instead of failure m.

Comment: Why then don't you correct your question ?

Comment: My apologies, I corrected the question itself but forgot about the title. It is now fixed.

Comment: I was able to solve the equation by finding the probability that the number of successes is less than n in (n+m)-1 trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula holds if $n\leq m$

Oddly, if $m = n$, it represents the simplest way to solve the question of finding the *Pr* of **losing** a two player tournament of best of $(2m -1)$ matches.

In order to lose a $5$ set tennis match, for example, you can allow your opponent to win a maximum of $2$ of the $5$ sets, thus

$P(lose) =\dbinom5 0 p^0q^5 +\dbinom5 1 p^1q^4 + \dbinom 5 2 p^2q^3$